# Test whether the foloowing quadratic forms are Equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

Consider two quadratic forms:

$Q(x,y,z,w)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}+bw^{2}$  and

$P(x,y,z,w)=x^{2}+y^{2}+czw$.

For what type of values of $b$ & $c$ (real or complex or negative or positive or zero) $P$ & $Q$ are equivalent?

For 2 or 3 variables we can do it easily using some theorems (If $Q$ is non-degenerate quadratic form in $n-variables$over $\mathbb{C}$ then $Q$ is equivalent to $x_{1}^{2}+...+x_{n}^{2}$.) or finding $rank$ , $discrimanant$, $etc$.

But for 4 variables how we can proceed? Are there any general rule to show two quadratic forms equivalent for arbitrary $n-variables$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question amounts to finding when the matrices
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&1\\&&&b}, \quad 
B = \pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&0&c/2\\&&c/2&0}
$$
are [congruent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence).

The answer in this case will be that the forms are equivalent iff $b < 0$ and $c \neq 0$.

Comment: @SayantanPanja yes. If $A$ and $B$ are symmetric (or Hermitian), then the quadratic forms $x^TAx$ and $x^TBx$ are **equivalent** if and only if the matrices $A$ and $B$ are **congruent**.

Comment: tHEN HOW WE SHOW THAT THE MATRICES ARE CONGRUENT?

Comment: I was hoping perhaps that you would have found that in the wikipedia article.  I quote: *"[Sylvester's law of intertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia) states that two congruent symmetric matrices with real entries have the same numbers of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues."* $B$ will have three positive eigenvalues and one non-negative eigenvalue whenever $c \neq 0$ ($c \in \Bbb R$), and will have two positive and two zero when $c = 0$.  $A$ will have three positive eigenvalues, and its last is equal to $b$ (I'm assuming $b \in \Bbb R$).

Comment: It is unusual to discuss the congruence of "quadratic forms" that cannot be represented by Hermitian matrices, such as those that we get when we allow $b,c \in \Bbb C$.

Comment: Sir, I know that, two congruent symmetric matrices with real entries have the same numbers of positive, negative, and zero eigenvalues. But I don't know whether the converse holds or not. i.e. if two matrices with entries have the same number of positive , negative and zero eigen values then are they congruent?

Comment: Yes. Any two matrices with the same such properties are congruent. This might be clear if you [skimmed through the page that I linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Statement_in_terms_of_eigenvalues).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom can you kindly explain me what will happen if we consider $b$ and $c$ as complex numbers?

Comment: @KprimeX the whole thing becomes a mess. I'm actually not sure what it would mean for two quadratic forms to be "equivalent" over $\Bbb C$, since we can no longer assume that they are Hermitian without loss of generality.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witt%27s_theorem#Witt.27s_cancellation_theorem

Reduce it to $z^2 + b\, w^2$ and $c \,z w$ are equivalent.

Comment: quick question: are you oranges kid, or an orange skid?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: kid me not!